# Is there any method available in officejs to close the word document ? Or "how we can open word document in same instance"

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, office-js-helpers

Is there any method available in officejs to close the word document ? Or "how we can open word document in same instance (if there is an instance already open)".

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no word API to close word document. For "open word document", this is API named createDocument, not sure if it can meet your requirement or not

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.application?view=word-js-preview#createdocument-base64file-

Comment: Thanks @MandytMSFT, I went through this API and it creates new instance instead of same instance (if an instance is already open)

Comment: @MandytMSFT Is there any plan to add the context.document.close() method any time soon? Since, currently when we open a document via context.application.createDocument(base64).open() the document is opened in a new instance. Can we open this document in the current instance?